# Angular 2: No spacing between bootstrap buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

On the following site: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

There is a space between the demo buttons on the boostrap site, but when I used them on my site, there's no space between. I've used developer tools to examine the styles but can't figure out what's causing that space.

Here's the code:

app.ts

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" *ngFor="let room of rooms">{{room.Name}}</button>
   </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  rooms:Array<any> = [
      {Name: 'Room 1'},
      {Name: 'Room 2'},
      {Name: 'Room 3'},
      {Name: 'Room 4'},
    ]
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base href="." />
    <title>angular2 playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js@2.4.1/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>
    loading...
  </my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is a plunker showing my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/68Au4swU0Oi63PQFOn5L?p=preview

Can anyone help?

Comment: We will need your code to compare. Perhaps share the link to your site or all of the relevant code snippets.

Comment: Show us a code snippet with YOUR code

Comment: this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgoo8wa7/) with **inline block** elements also has spacing:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behavior in contrary of the demo you provided, is that you are iterating the buttons. If you add them without the loop, they render just like as you would wish. I would suggest you actually use CSS for this purpose. Just add a margin between the buttons in CSS:

```
.btn{
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Your updated [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3A45Tsz89y3hH7eCv2Kd?p=preview)

Comment: that's not a true answer.

Answer (score 3):

in angular to fix that issue you need to add preserveWhitespaces: true the tsConfig :

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "preserveWhitespaces": true  // add this line in tsconfig.json
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Their  display property set to inline-block which add 4px space by default.....that's why people don't use display: inline-block to create flexible grid

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question which shows the code and the plunker. inline-block is the style on the buttons, but it doesn't create a space